# How to access previous support articles?

Tags: websites

I picked up an older G5 with a PowerPC for software testing. Its not booting, and I am experiencing the issues described at [3 Beep on Powermac G5](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/767164) on the Apple Forums. Unfortunately, the links provided for support articles were broken by Apple's webmaster. For example, this was cited at least 5 times, and it appears to be the canonical reference for this issue on the G5:

- http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?artnum=302527

Now, here's the best part. On the new support site, there is no search box. So it appears I can't even search for it based on the previous article number.

How do I reference previous support articles on the redesigned site?

Answer (score 1):

If you are lost on the Apple support globe and its new appearance and older forum links are leading to nowhere, the wayback machine may be helpful:

[About the Power Mac G5 (Late 2005) diagnostic LEDs](http://web.archive.org/web/20080420234615/http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?artnum=302527)

This support article doesn't mention beeps but only flashes and colors.

BTW the Apple support site still features searches:

[image]

The result is not very helpful though, despite the fact that the article is still available in the [archive](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT2652). I haven't been able to find it in the 100 listed results.

Answer (score 1):

There's always archive.org's [Wayback Machine](http://archive.org/web/). Of course, the archive doesn't necessarily have a copy the site or page you're looking for, and sometimes images and other resources are not available, but it's worth a shot.

In this case, it looks like [you're in luck](https://web.archive.org/web/20080303102549/http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?artnum=302527)!

---

[image: led image chart]

---

I'm with you, though -- Apple's support content not as well preserved as it ought to be.